# Which is the correct JOIN to use in this case?

Tags: mysql, join

I have three tables named exam, student and subject.

You can learn more about the data by checking this link: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b80b08d0517678b8da3b70d489462d4f

I want to see the columns test, sub_code, marks from exam table and name column from subject table. I will use WHERE clause to get data of a particular roll number.

I came up with this query:

```sql
SELECT exam.test "Test", subject.name "Subject", exam.sub_code "Subject Code", exam.marks "Marks"
FROM exam
INNER JOIN subject ON exam.sub_code = subject.sub_code
WHERE roll_no=1
ORDER BY exam.test,exam.sub_code;
```

but I am not sure if this is the correct way to join the tables. I just followed help from people in one of the Stack Overflow chatrooms and online articles; so I am not sure if this is the correct JOIN to use.

I tried using this https://joins.spathon.com/ but I could not understand which JOIN is correct because of the huge number of records in exam table (and I am a noob in JOIN statements).

Should I use LEFT JOIN or JOIN or some other method?

Also, is it possible to format SQL output like this:

```
+------+-----------------------+--------------+-------+
| Test | Subject               | Subject Code | Marks |
+------+-----------------------+--------------+-------+
| MT1  | Maths                 | 041          |    29 |
|      | Physics               | 042          |    36 |
|      | Chemistry             | 043          |    42 |
|      | Informatics Practices | 065          |    46 |
|      | English               | 301          |    38 |
+------+-----------------------+--------------+-------+
| MT2  | Maths                 | 041          |    37 |
|      | Physics               | 042          |    43 |
|      | Chemistry             | 043          |    45 |
|      | Informatics Practices | 065          |    48 |
|      | English               | 301          |    40 |
+------+-----------------------+--------------+-------+
| MT3  | Maths                 | 041          |    42 |
|      | Physics               | 042          |    40 |
|      | Chemistry             | 043          |    37 |
|      | Informatics Practices | 065          |    45 |
|      | English               | 301          |    45 |
+------+-----------------------+--------------+-------+
```

Comment: I put in a correction re. `OUTER` joins - I was lazy in my use of terminology and apologise - the only case in which `OUTER` joins would not be applicable is if **every** student had an exam result in **every** exam for **every** subject - that's not the case. I was too hasty in my response - I've put in an explanation of how `OUTER` joins could be used with your data at the beginning of my answer!

Answer (score 3):

Your `INNER JOIN` is suitable for the summarising type of queries - although an `OUTER JOIN` (in this case `LEFT`) can be useful, for example:

```
SELECT
  e.roll_no,  e.sub_code, e.marks, e.test,
  COALESCE(sb.name, '----') AS s_name, COALESCE(sb.sub_code, '----') AS s_code
FROM
  exam e
LEFT JOIN
  subject sb ON e.sub_code = sb.sub_code
WHERE sb.name IS NULL;
```

Result (`----` = NULL):

```
roll_no sub_code    marks   test    s_name  s_code
      3      044       29    MT1    ----    ----
      5      044       39    MT1    ----    ----
     16      044       43    MT1    ----    ----
      3      044       33    MT2    ----    ----
      5      044       40    MT2    ----    ----
     16      044       38    MT2    ----    ----
      3      044       40    MT3    ----    ----
      5      044       42    MT3    ----    ----
     16      044       40    MT3    ----    ----
```

So, students 3, 5 & 16 have marks in an exam (subject code 044 - 3 tests each MT1, MT2 & MT3 - 9 grades in total) for a subject which apparently doesn't exist in the subject table. A check of the data reveals that `("040","Biology");` should probably be `("044","Biology");` - see the last snippet of this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a79d471a1d2a8cbb2f37623dc76a895f).

This part about the `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` was put in following a comment by @RickJames about how I was too quick off the mark saying that because there were no `NULL`s in the data, `OUTER JOIN`s didn't apply - this was incorrect in the general sense - for the aggregates that you want, it is correct, but an unfortunate over-generalisation on my part and clumsily put!

The `OUTER` keyword is useful when you want to see what "isn't there" - i.e. how many students **didn't** take any exams, or didn't take the `MT3` ones? How many subjects had **no** exams?

For your **summarising**, the best you can do with MySQL is something like the SQL below (all of the code  is available on the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6c923fc5e3404e1d5a2ae1f487be7947)). If you want nice formatting, then I suggest that you investigate ([Open Source] Business Intelligence tools - that is what they are for, not what an RDBMS is for)!

Note `WITH ROLLUP`!

```
SELECT 
  exam.test AS "Test", 
  subject.name AS "Subject", 
  exam.sub_code AS "Subject Code", 
  exam.marks AS "Marks", 
  MIN(exam.marks), MAX(exam.marks), AVG(exam.marks)
FROM exam
INNER JOIN subject ON exam.sub_code = subject.sub_code  -- INNER is optional - left in for clarity
WHERE roll_no=1
GROUP BY exam.test, subject.name, exam.sub_code, exam.marks WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY 
  ISNULL(exam.test), exam.test ASC,  -- ASC is the default, but I like including it!
  ISNULL(subject.name), subject.name ASC,
  ISNULL(exam.sub_code), exam.sub_code ASC,
  ISNULL(exam.marks), exam.marks ASC;
```

Result: (Note `-----` and `-1' are placeholders for` NULL`!)

```
Test    Subject Subject Code    Marks   MIN(exam.marks) MAX(exam.marks) AVG(exam.marks)
MT1 Chemistry      043    42      42    42    42.0000
MT1 Chemistry      043    -1      42    42    42.0000
MT1 Chemistry    ----     -1      42    42    42.0000
MT1 English        301    38      38    38    38.0000
MT1 English        301    -1      38    38    38.0000
MT1 English       ----    -1      38    38    38.0000
MT1 IP(*)          065    46      46    46    46.0000  -- (*) Informatics Practices
...
... snipped for brevity
...
MT1 Physics      ----     -1      36    36    36.0000
MT1 --------     ----     -1      29    46    38.2000  -- End of MT1 - overall AVG/MAX/MIN for MT1
MT2 Chemistry     043     45      45    45    45.0000
...
...
...
49 rows   -- Note - 49 rows!
```

See the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) on `WITH ROLLUP`. PostgreSQL's [functionality](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/queries-table-expressions.html) is a bit more sophisticated, but even so, I'd go for [window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.htm) (and follow links at bottom) in this case - IMHO, looks neater and you can easily pick out your values of interest by putting an outer query around this one below:

```
SELECT 
  e.test AS "Test", 
  s.name AS "Subject", 
  e.sub_code AS "Subject Code", 
  e.marks AS "Marks",
  ROUND(AVG(e.marks) OVER (PARTITION BY e.sub_code), 1) AS "Avg/subj",
  ROUND(AVG(e.marks) OVER (PARTITION BY e.test), 1)     AS "Avg/test",
  ROUND(AVG(e.marks) OVER (), 1)                        AS "Avg overall"
FROM exam e
INNER JOIN subject s 
  ON e.sub_code = s.sub_code
WHERE roll_no = 1
ORDER BY e.test, e.sub_code;
```

Result:

```
Test   Subject  Subject Code  Marks  Avg/subj   Avg/test    Avg overall
 MT1     Maths           041     29      36.0       38.2           40.9
 MT1   Physics           042     36      39.7       38.2           40.9
 MT1 Chemistry           043     42      41.3       38.2           40.9
 MT1    IP (*)           065     46      46.3       38.2           40.9
 MT1   English           301     38      41.0       38.2           40.9
 MT2     Maths           041     37      36.0       42.6           40.9
 ...
 ... snipped for brevity
 ...
 15 rows    -- Note 15 rows!
```

So, no need for nasty `NULL` placeholders (`-----`, `-1`), fewer lines of output (15 vs. 49 - 49 = 15 * 3 + 3 lines for the test averages + 1 summary line)

A couple of points:

- use aliases (`FROM exam e`) in your queries - it makes them more readable and less error-prone
- learn about window functions - they are **extremely** powerful and will repay any effort spent learning them many times over!

Following a comment by the OP, I did a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ddfb096e75bdf656f6c5254832243fc4) with averages per test and overall, and per subject, per test and overall - either you get 3 rows or 15 - but 5 is not possible!

Comment: I don't need the minimum, maximum and average :)

Comment: "you have no NULLs in your data" -- Wrong.  A `LEFT JOIN` creates `NULLs` by not finding a row in the 'right' table.  I'm sorry, but that is so wrong that I am stopping there and downvote the Answer.

Comment: @RickJames - I put in a correction acknowledging your input at the beginning of my answer. I shall endeavour to avoid lazy terminology in future and thank you for pointing out my error!

Comment: @Vérace - Thanks.  Downvote removed.

Comment: @Vérace-getVACCINATEDNOW Thanks for pointing out about the wrong subject code of Biology. So I feel having `LEFT JOIN` is way better in my situation to avoid issues like these.

Comment: I think that @RickJames put it best when he wrote: `The type of JOIN you need will always depend ​on your data and your goals.` It can't be put any better or more simply than that - all `JOIN` types have their use cases (that's why they're there). If you want to see students who didn't take any exams or courses that have no students (or, my example, people who have results for subjects which don't exist) , then `[LEFT | RIGHT] [OUTER] JOINS` will be useful. You should use FOREIGN KEYs to ensure from the get-go that this can't happen! Your DDL is the last bastion of defence that your db has!

Comment: I think that was J.D. who wrote that.  But I agree.  Notes:  MySQL ignores `OUTER` and does not directly implement `FULL`.  FKs provide an index (for performance) and a constraint (for consistency check).

Answer (score 2):

The type of `JOIN` you need will always depend ​on your data and your goals.

The most common types of `JOIN`s are as follows:

1. `INNER JOIN` aka `JOIN` - Returns **only** rows that match on your join clause in **both** entities.
2. `LEFT OUTER JOIN` aka `LEFT JOIN` - Returns **all** rows from the entity specified on the left side of the `LEFT JOIN` keyword, and **only matching** rows from the entity on the right side. `NULL` is filled in for the fields of the entity from the right side for the rows that don't match the entity from the left.
3. `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` aka `RIGHT JOIN` - Essentially the same as the `LEFT JOIN` but the *direction* is flipped. So now the entity on the **right** side will return **all** of its rows and **only matching** rows from the left side are returned.
4. `FULL OUTER JOIN` aka `FULL JOIN` - Returns **all** rows from **both** entities on each side. Where the rows match, the data is returned for both entities, where they don't match, `NULL` is filled in for the values of the columns of the one side that doesn't match the other. *Note this doesn't functionally exist as a keyword in MySQL, but as a concept is good to be aware of and can be accomplished by using a `UNION` clause between a `LEFT JOIN` and `RIGHT JOIN`.
5. `CROSS JOIN` - Returns the **cross product** of **both** entities. So a row is returned for **every combination** of each row between both entities.

So in your case you're joining between `exam` and `subject`. Specifically in your example you chose an `INNER JOIN`. This will only return rows where the `sub_code` exists in both tables. That means if you have a row for an `exam` that doesn't have a `sub_code` defined yet or was deleted from the `subject` table, then that `exam` row won't be returned. But you may know that such a situation isn't possible in your system, and therefore an `INNER JOIN` is ok here.

Conversely, if you wanted to list all `subjects` and their correlating exams, regardless if a particular `subject` even has any `exams` yet then an `INNER JOIN` wouldn't work since any `subject` without a correlating `exam` (no `sub_code` for a row in the `exam` table) would not be returned. Instead you'd want to use an `OUTER JOIN`, and specifically with the order of how you wrote the tables in your query, you'd want a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` to ensure **all** rows from the `subject` table are returned, and **any** matching rows from the `exam` table are returned.

You may find this article on [SQL JOINs](https://learnsql.com/blog/sql-joins/) with visuals of each join type helpful as well.

Comment: What does normal `JOIN` do?

Comment: @RandomPerson As I mentioned in my answer, that's a keyword equivalent to `INNER JOIN`. They mean the same exact thing.

Comment: Of note: MySQL does not implement `FULL JOIN`.  It can be simulated with help from a `UNION`.  (I find it to be _very_ rarely needed.)

Comment: @RickJames Good point, I don't use MySQL enough that I forgot this. I put a note in my answer, thanks!

Comment: @J.D. "*But you may know that such a situation isn't possible in your system, and therefore an `INNER JOIN` is ok here.*" Actually there was a mistake in the sub_code of Biology in the subject table (it should have been 044, but I typed 040). Because of this, few rows went missing. Using LEFT JOIN helped me identify the issue. I prefer LEFT JOIN more than RIGHT JOIN because the data from the exam table is more important.

Comment: @RandomPerson Right, it's situational and depends on your data and use cases. Though keep in mind in the case where you know for a fact an `INNER JOIN` is appropriate, then it's also potentially a more performant join operator than an outer join too.